# How would I rename a local table (and not the shortcut to a local table) in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access

I have created a local table in Access 2016 named `rptLeqTable`.

I tried to rename the table in the Access Navigation Pane.

After renaming the newly created table from `rptLeqTable` to `rptMetricsTable`, I looked at the Table Properties.

The table properties still shows the original table name and refers to it as a

```
Shortcut to Table (Local): rptLeqTable.
```

[image: Table properties]

There is no entry in the Navigation Pane for an object named `rptLeqTable`.

Is there any way to rename the actual local table (and not just the shortcut)?

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are renaming the shortcut in a *custom category group* you have created:

[image]

Go to Object view, Tables, and rename the table itself.

(Source: Andy Tabisz)